# Making a branch from repo history?

Tags: git, github

I have a branch deep down in my repo, around 15 commits earlier. I'd like to make that into a branch. Any way I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the commit that you want to branch from then branch.

Get the commit hash from the log e.g. ab3213e

```
git checkout ab3213e
git checkout -b my_new_branch
```

Answer (score 4):

Using your commit reference, the following will create a new branch from it. You can use relative or absolute commit references—eg. `HEAD~15` or `d3adb33f`—both work fine.

```sh
# Create a branch from HEAD~15, but do not switch HEAD to this new branch
$ git branch branch-name HEAD~15

# Create a branch from d3adb33f and switch to it
$ git checkout -b branch-name d3adb33f
```